# Child router outlet works only one time

Tags: javascript, routes, angular5, router-outlet

The router outlet works only the first time. No issues or errors. I have a child routing to one component.
Routing works correct URL is changing in a browser, but the component doesn't invoke the second time.

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: '', component: InvestmentComponent, children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full'},
            { path: 'coin/:cointype/:hashaddress', component: MNWalletComponent },
        ]
    },
])
```

component html:

```
 <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="coin/{{coins[0].coin.coinType}}/{{coins[0].hashaddress}}"> 
            <appc-coin [coin]="coins[0].coin"></appc-coin>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="coin/{{coins[1].coin.coinType}}/{{coins[1].hashaddress}}"> 
            <appc-coin [coin]="coins[1].coin"></appc-coin>
        </a>
    </li>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) maybe?

Comment: There is a problem It is work on simple example.